# Remove overlapping of bars from barchart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, overlap

I have created a barchart but the bars from the two data sets are overlying one another. I was wondering if anyone could help me separate the bars of the two data sets so they are sitting side by side rather than overlapping. Both of the categories for the x axis are exactly the same. Here is my code:

```
h.length.category <- sabdata.dat[,"H_Length_Category"]
h.length.sum <- sabdata.dat[,"H_Length_Sum"]

v.length.category <- sabdata.dat[,"V_Length_Category"]
v.length.sum <- sabdata.dat[,"V_Length_Sum"]

hum.len <- tapply(h.length.sum, list(h.length.category), sum)
ven.len <- tapply(v.length.sum, list(v.length.category), sum)

barplot(hum.len, ylim = c(0,80), las = 2, xlab = "Length (mm)", ylab = "Number of individuals", col = "dark grey")
par(new=T)
barplot(ven.len, ylim = c(0,80), las = 2, xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, col = "light grey")
par(new=F)
```

Here's a subset of the data:

```
H_Length_Category   H_Length_Sum    V_Length_Category   V_Length_Sum

08-09.9             0               08-09.9             1
10-11.9             0               10-11.9             10
12-13.9             3               12-13.9             31
14-15.9             12              14-15.9             58
16-17.9             30              16-17.9             66
18-19.9             35              18-19.9             77
20-21.9             62              20-21.9             64
22-23.9             63              22-23.9             41
```

Comment: It would help if your code was reproducible.  Can you provide your data or at least a subset?

Comment: You could use `ggplot`, with `position_dodge` so that your bars don't overlap, but it would be nice to have some example data to give a fuller answer.

Comment: You could stack hum.len and ven.len into a data frame or matrix and use a single call to barplot with `beside = TRUE` `hum.len <- with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, gear, sum)); ven.len <- with(mtcars, tapply(wt, gear, sum)); dat <- rbind(hum.len, ven.len); barplot(dat, beside = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening--without having seen your data--is that you're trying to overlay two different plots on the same set of axes.  As a result, you're covering up what gets what was plotted first:

```
    #make up some data
    x <- c(10, 11, 12, 16)
    y <- c(9, 12, 10, 13)

    barplot(x)
    barplot(y, col = "yellow", add = T) #The add statement is effectively the same as what you coded above
```

[image: Essentially, an overlaid plot]
However, if all of your data is in one matrix,

```
    dF <- as.matrix(cbind(x, y))
    barplot(dF, beside = T)
```

The result is probably much closer to what you're looking for.  Depending upon your data and how you want to present it, you may have to determine how your matrix is formatted to display what you want to display.

[image: A plot with all of the data in a matrix]

Comment: Or: `barplot(cbind(hum.len,ven.len),beside=T)` with OP's data.